# "Canalized" usage in "a great impact which can also be canalized"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, passive-voice

I'm in doubt if this is the correct usage of the word *canalized*:

> In the US a researching team found that pure entertainment, such as TV series or movies, have a great impact which can also be **canalized** towards educational needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct figurative usage; [Merriam-Webster’s definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canalize) include “to direct into preferred channels”, and their sample usage is quite similar to your example:

> The director of the charity should be *canalizing* the flow of donations so that the money ends up where it is most needed.

On the other hand, it sounds quite stilted to my ear; *channelled* would seem completely equivalent, and is much more commonly used.  Obligatory (but quite interesting) [Google Ngrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=channelled+into%2Cchannelled+towards%2Ccanalized+into%2Ccanalized+towards&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

[image: Google Ngrams chart for channelled/canalized into/towards]

Perhaps *canalize* is more common as a piece of jargon, or possibly as a technical term, within some business or charity communities, with subtly different connotations from *channel*?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you doubt it?

> [**canalize**](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/canalize) |ˈkanəlˌīz|
>   *verb* [ trans. ]
>   convert (a river) into a navigable canal.
>   • convey (something) through a duct or channel.
>   • figurative give a direction or purpose to (something) : *his strategy was to canalize the enthusiasm of the diehards into party channels*.
>   [encyclopedia.com]

The usage you cite is figurative, describing the channeling of an already existing force into a beneficial usage of some kind.

Comment: I suppose OP's whole point is that an impact is not a force, it's the end result of a force. You can give direction to a meteorite that's still moving, but not to a crater that's already there.

Comment: _Canalized_ has a very technical usage in evolutionary biology; I certainly wasn't aware it had an ordinary definition, that is easily gleaned from the word's morphology, myself.  There, it means something like the state of having many different genotypes that produce the same phenotype.  I'm actually fairly at a loss to see how the ordinary definition relates to the technical one.

Comment: I should have stated it in the question, but I was also wandering about if it sounded good. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You should cite the dictionary you got this from... (even after all these years.)

Comment: @Laurel: quite so.